# pip getting killed in Docker

Tags: python, macos, docker, pip, out-of-memory

I am building a Docker container based on `python:3.7-slim-stretch` (same problem also happens on `python:3.7-slim-stretch`), and it is getting `Killed` on

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --verbose /wheels/*
```

My Mac (OSX 10.15.7) has 64Gb of RAM, and plenty of disk space, so I have no idea why it is being killed. How can I find out? (I saw a suggestion to check `/var/log/messages`... but it doesn't exist...) And then, what can I do about it?

(Also, interestingly, the initial `pip wheel` works perfectly fine.)

Just in case, here's the `Dockerfile`:

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y build-essential mecab

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch

ENV HOME=/home/app APP_HOME=/home/app/web

RUN mkdir -p /home/app $APP_HOME \
    && addgroup --system app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY --chown=app:app --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --chown=app:app --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --verbose --no-cache-dir /wheels/*

COPY --chown=app:app . $APP_HOME

USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and `requirements.txt`:

```
aiofiles==0.6.0
alabaster==0.7.12
allennlp==0.9.0
attrs==20.3.0
Babel==2.9.0
blinker==1.4
blis==0.2.4
boto3==1.17.10
botocore==1.20.10
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
conllu==1.3.1
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.5
dataclasses==0.6
docutils==0.16
editdistance==0.5.3
filelock==3.0.12
flaky==3.7.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
ftfy==5.9
gevent==21.1.2
greenlet==1.0.0
h11==0.12.0
h2==4.0.0
h5py==3.1.0
hpack==4.0.0
Hypercorn==0.11.2
hyperframe==6.0.0
idna==2.10
imagesize==1.2.0
importlib-metadata==3.4.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==1.0.1
jsonnet==0.17.0
jsonpickle==2.0.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
mecab-python3==0.996.5
mojimoji==0.0.11
murmurhash==1.0.5
nltk==3.5
numpy==1.20.1
numpydoc==1.1.0
overrides==3.1.0
packaging==20.9
parsimonious==0.8.1
Pillow==8.1.0
plac==0.9.6
pluggy==0.13.1
preshed==2.0.1
priority==1.3.0
protobuf==3.14.0
py==1.10.0
Pygments==2.8.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.2.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytorch-pretrained-bert==0.6.2
pytorch-transformers==1.1.0
pytz==2021.1
Quart==0.14.1
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.1
responses==0.12.1
s3transfer==0.3.4
sacremoses==0.0.43
scikit-learn==0.24.1
scipy==1.6.1
sentencepiece==0.1.95
six==1.15.0
snowballstemmer==2.1.0
spacy==2.1.9
Sphinx==3.5.1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
sqlparse==0.4.1
srsly==1.0.5
tensorboardX==2.1
thinc==7.0.8
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tokenizers==0.8.1rc1
toml==0.10.2
torch==1.7.1
tqdm==4.57.0
transformers==3.0.2
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
Unidecode==1.2.0
urllib3==1.26.3
wasabi==0.8.2
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==1.0.1
word2number==1.1
wsproto==1.0.0
zipp==3.4.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

Comment: Can you post the docker stats output? How much RAM your Mac has is of little importance if your container isn't allowed to use it. Try increasing the limit to as much as possible, and seeing what happens.

Comment: Yeah, probably obvious, but if you haven't you may want to check your container RAM/disk settings: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/ . On Windows when I run out of RAM in my container, it just gets killed like that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm Docker newbie, so you just taught me about `docker stats` as well as limits. Some googling later and I'm trying to mess with `docker-compose build -m [size]` and i can set it _lower_ than the default 1.943GiB, but not higher. @xdhmoore provided the crucial piece of the puzzle — DockerForMac has the global limit in its preferences, and raising it worked. If you want to submit, the bounty is yours.

Comment: woot, party....

Comment: Unlikely it's related to your memory issues, but note you don't need to install MeCab with apt if you use the version in your requirements.txt - in fact, the version you install via apt will be ignored. I also recommend upgrading to the latest version. (If you are building neologd that could consume a ton of memory and be related.)

Comment: @polm23 Oh, thanks. Yeah, it doesn't seem to be needed. I don't remember well, but I think I was messing about with different images and had issues with `mecab-python3` installation, so it got left behind as a relic of past attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experience something similar on Windows when my docker containers run out of memory in WSL. I think the settings are different for Mac, but it looks like there is info here on setting the VM RAM/disk size/swap file settings for Docker for Desktop on Mac:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac